# WoW installer asks for "DiscName1"

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm having trouble installing WoW. I put in the discs when the installer prompted me to, but now it's asking me to put in something called "DiscName1". The game pack I bought only has two discs. How can I complete the installation?

Comment: Put in the first disk?

Comment: Where'd you get the game pack from?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you own a valid and legit copy of WoW, you can always choose to visit [battle.net](http://battle.net), register there<sup>**1**</sup>, redeem the code provided with your copy of WoW, and finally download the installer from there.

No discs, no hassle. The only downside is that you'll have to download quite a lot of data<sup>**2**</sup>, which will take some time. But then again, you'll probably have to wait just as long to download all patches after you successfully installed the game from disk.

---

<sup>**1**</sup>: You'll have to register to play anyways, so now's as good a time as any.
<sup>**2**</sup>: The installer itself isn't very big. It's just like a torrent client, which means you don't have to download everything in one session.

Comment: Honestly, you'll probably end up downloading less data installing directly from the website than you will by trying to install the game from disc and then patching up to date.